# Webpack Hot Module Replacement + React

Tags: reactjs, webpack, hot-reload

Probably it's one of thousands of similar questions, but I still didn't see any answer about how to make HMR **REALLY** work.

I did all that manipulations, described in [docs](https://webpack.js.org/guides/hot-module-replacement/#enabling-hmr) and in every answer you can find all over internet:

- enable "hot" option of webpack-dev-server
- add `webpack-dev-server/client?{host:port}` and `webpack/hot/only-dev-server` entry points
- add `new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()` to plugins (and NamedModulesPlugin too)
- every step from docs of [react-hot-loader](https://github.com/gaearon/react-hot-loader#getting-started)

And now what I have.

Let say my app looks like this:

```
<ReactRouter>
  <App>
    <AppRouter />
  </App>
</ReactRouter>
```

where `AppRouter` is like

```
<Switch>
  <Route path="..." component={Page} />
  ...
</Switch>
```

and `Page` is just `<div>some text<div>`.

Accordingly to docs, in App module I do:

```
import { hot } from "react-hot-loader"
export default hot(module)(App)
```

and then trying to modify text in `Page` component to "new text".

In console I see that HMR is enabled indeed:

```
[WDS] App hot update...
[HMR] Checking for updates on the server...
[HMR] Updated modules:
[HMR]  - ./Page.js
[HMR]  - ./AppRouter.js
[HMR]  - ./App.js
[HMR] App is up to date.
```

and text on screen really updates to "new text". So far so good.

Then I update text once again, to "new text 2", and see this:

```
Ignored an update to unaccepted module ./Page.js -> ./AppRouter.js -> ./App.js
[HMR] The following modules couldn't be hot updated: (They would need a full reload!)
[HMR]  - ./Page.js
```

There is **nothing** about this in `react-hot-loader` docs.

But ok, maybe that doc is slightly incorrect. After all, webpack own docs explicitly shows that we should do `module.hot.accept(...)` in our code.

So in `App.js` I do:

```
if (module.hot) {
  module.hot.accept("./AppRouter", () => {
    console.log("It works!")
  })
}
```

then refreshing the page, and trying to modify `Page` component again.

Now console says following:

```
[WDS] App hot update...
[HMR] Checking for updates on the server...
App.js:20 It works!
[HMR] Updated modules:
[HMR]  - ./Page.js
[HMR]  - ./AppRouter.js
[HMR]  - ./App.js
[HMR] App is up to date.
```

But **text in browser is not updated**. I.e., HMR is enabled but does nothing.

Succeeding updates says:

```
[WDS] App hot update...
[HMR] Checking for updates on the server...
[HMR] Updated modules:
[HMR]  - ./Page.js
[HMR] App is up to date.
```

so at least we fixed previous error with `unaccepted changes` – but still nothing changes in browser.

I tried to do `module.hot.accept(...)` both when App is decorated with `hot(module)` and when it's not – result is the same.

And... what next? I did everything I can find in official docs, and nothing of it works. What am I doing wrong?

*(and please, please don't ask "provide your full webpack config before we talk". It's all default, accordingly to example from webpack docs. Don't waste our time on this)*

Answer (score 0):

When you accept a file, you have to do the things yourself (the exchanging of the component for example). So do sth. like this:

```
if (module.hot) {
  module.hot.accept("./AppRouter", () => {
    const NewAppRouter = require('./AppRouter').default;
    const newApp = (
       <ReactRouter>
          <App>
             <NewAppRouter />
          </App>
       </ReactRouter>
    );
    ReactDom.render(newApp, container);
  });
}
```

Here I get notified when the file changed. Then I require the changed file and rerender my app with the new file. This works best, when you use a statemanagement lib like redux or mobx, because your application's state won't change when you rerender your app.